# Function to display nth element of a list, is returning false.

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have a function I am using to return the nth element of a list.

```
dispnth([H|T], 0, H).  
 dispnth([H|T], C, Result) :-
 dispnth(T, NewC, H), NewC is C -1.
```

With an input like 
    dispnth([1, 2, 3, 4], 2, X).

I should get

```
X=2.
```

But I am getting false.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check your last line :

```
dispnth([H|T], 0, H).  
dispnth([H|T], C, Result) :-
   dispnth(T, NewC, H), NewC is C -1.
```

Should be

```
dispnth([H|T], 0, H).  
dispnth([H|T], C, Result) :-
   Newc is C - 1,
   dispnth(T, Newc, Result).
```

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, with the input `dispnth([1, 2, 3, 4], 2, X).` you should get `X=3` and not `X=2` as it is as if your array was zero-indexed. Or else you should replace the 0 in the first predicate with a 1.